# How can a list-control be redrawn after changing its alignment style?

Tags: listview, mfc, clistctrl, listctrl, listcontrol

I am trying to figure out a way to refresh/update/redraw a list-control after its alignment style (`LVS_ALIGNTOP` / `LVS_ALIGNLEFT`) has been changed.

If I change the style from icon/small mode to something else then back again, it works sometimes (only when clicking, programmatically changing doesn’t seem to work even with a delay). Even so, that is pretty kludgey at best (not to mention ugly/flickery) so I would prefer to find a better (more appropriate, more correct?) way.

I tried the list-control’s `UpdateWindow`, `RedrawWindow`, `Invalidate`, `RedrawItems`, `Update`… nothing seems to work other than changing the display mode.

Comment: Did you ever come toa conclusion?

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully used the CListCtrl.Update() method to solve this issue.

ie:

```
for (int z=0;z<m_listCtrl.GetItemCount();z++)
{
    m_listCtrl.Update(z);
}
```

Comment: Well I’ve already indicated that I have tried `Update`. I don’t really remember what project I was working on at the time I ran into this issue, but I’ll try to find out and test if maybe doing it in a loop is the trick (assuming of course that I didn’t already).

Comment: Well I found the project and I tried it in a loop, but it doesn’t work; the list control remains in the previous alignment.

Answer (score 1):

Found out what you had to do,

```
m_listCtrl.Arrange(LVA_DEFAULT);
```

you might need to change `LVA_DEFAULT` to your specific requirements. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kk0xwc3.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
RedrawItems(0, GetItemCount() - 1);
UpdateWindow();
```

Comment: Did you read the question? I clearly said I already tried that.